# How do I change the root directory of an Apache server?

Tags: linux, apache, lamp

How can I change the document root of the Apache server? I basically want `localhost` to come from `/users/spencer/projects` directory instead of `/var/www`.

---

I ended up figuring it out. Some suggested I change the `httpd.conf` file, but I ended up finding a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and changed the root directory from `/var/www` to `/home/myusername/projects_folder` and that worked.

Comment: Viewed 815k times, I never get stackoverflow moderators. So many stackoverflow users have to deal with apache cause it's how they distribute what the programmed. That it is so close to the field SO is about that I would not even consider this for closing due to being offtopic.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You need to change the `DocumentRoot` setting in your `httpd.conf` file.  Chances are it will be under something like `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.

Use your favourite editor (I recommend [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)) and look for the `DocumentRoot` and change it to `/users/spencer/projects`. Also look a little further down for a setting that looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
```

You will also want to change what is in the quotes to your new directory. This gives Apache access to read from that directory when a user makes a request that call on it.

Now restart your Apache service (`httpd -k restart`) and you should be good to go.

Apache 2 site configuration files are now typically kept in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` (Debian, Ubuntu, etc.).

Comment: I opened /etc/apache2/httpd.conf , but the file was blank. I am opening it with gedit.

Comment: The file might be in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, depending on your flavor of Linux.

Comment: the httpd.conf file is empty but I found a file at etc/apache2/sites-available/default and changed the root directory there. I prob should have mentioned that this is not on an actual server. I am setting up a local development environment. Not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: it's supposed to be empty @spencer. check here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=278531

Comment: @RDL (or others) My apache have no `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`, the `locate httpd.conf` returns only
`/etc/javascript-common/lighttpd.conf` ... What I do?  Create a new file or change this file?

Comment: @Peter Krauss, try doing a "which httpd" from the command line. That will tell you where the service is running from and the "conf" may be up a directory from there.

Comment: Thanks!  My conf (of a standard Apache!) was `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default/000-default.conf`, now is working with [similar modification (DocumentRoot) reported here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21831272/287948).

Comment: Would it be possible to enable both /var/www and /home/myusername/projects_folder at the same time? And how should I config? thanks.

Comment: I found mine (Xubuntu 14.04) in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: I Have made a script that changes the Apache root in single command. Link:https://github.com/hsb4995/Apachange

Comment: If you only change the documentroot in httpd.conf, it won't work if you have a virtual host for *:80, pointing elsewhere. So change the documentroot there too.

Comment: The "answer" is really obsolete. 
Correct answer according to Ubuntu 18.x docs is
Either change the root directory of Apache or move the project to /var/www/html .

To change Apache's root directory, run: cd /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Then open the 000-default.conf file using the command: nano 000-default.conf.
Edit the DocumentRoot option: DocumentRoot /path/to/my/project.

(see https://askubuntu.com/questions/337874/change-apache-document-root-folder-to-secondary-hard-drive)

Comment: My server does not have conf folder, this answer is so obsolete

Comment: @FernandoTorres read the last line of the answer. It gives the updated directory.

Comment: To run Apache in a user directory you need to add the user to the Apache group and the Apache to the user group. I suggest adding the following 3 commands to the answer: Open the terminal with your user and run: sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER; sudo adduser $USER www-data; sudo adduser www-data $USER;

Answer (score 296):

**Please note, that this only applies for [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr) and newer releases.**

In my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the document root was set to `/var/www/html`. It was configured in the following file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

So just do a

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and change the following line to what you want:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Also do a

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and find this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And change `/var/www/html` to your preferred directory and save it.

After you saved your changes, just restart the Apache 2 web server and you'll be done :)

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

If you prefer a graphical text editor, you can just replace the `sudo nano` with a `gksu gedit`.

Comment: On my ubuntu 13.10, I cannot find any *.conf files under /etc/apache2/sites-available/, is it because of different version?

Comment: @Paul Lo: I haven't tried this on Ubuntu 13.10, only on Ubuntu 14.04; As I'm pretty sure that the first time I set up apache (which was on Ubuntu 12.04), there was no such directory. So yes, I guess that this is only available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and newer. However, you can have a look at the other answers. The upvotes suggest that they helped other people, maybe they also work with Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: However thanks for asking, I just edited this information into the answer so that noone else walks into the trap of trying this with older Ubuntu versions (y)

Comment: @mozzbozzm, you are right. Only 14.04. Really a weird choice, now suddenly having `var/www/html` as default root. Are they actually **trying** to waste peoples time? :)

Comment: This finally worked, I am hosted in azure, i realised the server data was being cached somewhere, so had to add a fake query string to get the site with the new folder. whew!!!

Comment: I'm getting a forbidden error `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` when I hit localhost:80 in my browser. Do I need to change the port?

Comment: I had to add 000-default to sites-enabled: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf .

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Virtual_Hosts

Comment: @Costa did you figure it out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @MattG Oh, man, it's been so long, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Costa I solved the problem by adding    
`<Directory path_to_directory>

 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

 AllowOverride None

 Require all granted

</Directory> `

in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: So the first setting is the document root and the second is the rights management of the document root in apache2?

Comment: To run Apache in a user directory you need to add the user to the Apache group and the Apache to the user group. I suggest adding the following 3 commands to the answer: Open the terminal with your user and run: sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER; sudo adduser $USER www-data; sudo adduser www-data $USER;

Answer (score 45):

I had to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. The lines are the same as [mentioned by RDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server/5891858#5891858).

Comment: A suggested edit by @pabloab had this to say: "Apache 2.4 and above requires `.conf` at the end, and by default have a `000-` as prefix". The result is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. I haven't tested this out, but it may help some folks.

Comment: ^^ this fixed it. Where is it documented that I require .conf at the end of my sites-available files?!? I have about 20 virtual hosts that were disabled and offline after an update, and after a couple hours, finding this and renaming my sites-available files fixed it for me.

Comment: To run Apache in a user directory you need to add the user to the Apache group and the Apache to the user group. I suggest adding the following 3 commands to the answer: Open the terminal with your user and run: sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER; sudo adduser $USER www-data; sudo adduser www-data $USER;

Answer (score 32):

This is for [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr):

In file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` it should be as below without the directory name:

```
<Directory /home/username>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And in file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` you should include the custom directory name, i.e., *www*:

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/www
```

If it is not as above, it will give you an error when loading the server:

> Forbidden  You don't have permission to access / on this server

Comment: Thank you buddy :) This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It also worked on Debian 8

Comment: What do you mean by "without the directory name"?

Comment: To run Apache in a user directory you need to add the user to the Apache group and the Apache to the user group. I suggest adding the following 3 commands to the answer: Open the terminal with your user and run: sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER; sudo adduser $USER www-data; sudo adduser www-data $USER;

Comment: Perfect solution, thank!

Answer (score 23):

The right way to change directory or run from multiple directories under different port for Apache 2 is as follows:

For Apache 2, the configuration files are located under `/etc/apache2` and doesn’t use a single configuration file as in older versions but is split into smaller configuration files, with `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` being the main configuration file. To serve files from a different directory we need a new virtualhost conf file. The virtualhost configuration files are located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (do not edit files within sites-enabled). The default Apache installation uses virtualhost conf file `000-default.conf`.

Start by creating a new virtualhost file by copying the default virtualhost file used by the default installation of Apache (the one that runs at localhost on port 80). Change into directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and then make copy by `sudo cp 000-default.conf example.com.conf`, now edit the file by `sudo gedit example.com.conf` to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I have deleted the nonimportant lines from the above file for brevity. Here `DocumentRoot` is the path to the directory from which the website files are to be served such as `index.html`.

Create the directory from which you want to serve the files, for example, `mkdir example.com` and change owner and default group of the directory, for example, if your logged in user name is `ubuntu` change permissions as `sudo chown ubuntu:www-data example.com`. This grants full access to the user `ubuntu` and allows read and execute access to the group `www-data`.

Now edit the Apache configuration file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` by issuing command `sudo gedit apache2.conf` and find the line `<Directory /var/www/>` and below the closing tag `</Directory>`, add the following below:

```
<Directory /home/ubuntu/example.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now there are two commands to enable or disable the virtualhost configuration files, which are `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` respectively. Now since our `example.com.conf` file uses the same port(`80`) as used by the default configuration file(`000-default.conf`), we have to disable the default configuration file by issuing the command `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` and enable our virtualhost configuration file by `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`

Now restart or reload the server with command `sudo service apache2 restart`. Now Apache serves files from directory `example.com` at `localhost` on default port of `80`.

The `a2ensite` command basically creates a symbolic link to the configuration file under the site-enabled directory.

Do not edit files within sites-enabled (or *-enabled) directory, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812360/what-is-the-difference-between-sites-enabled-and-sites-available-directory/41568701#41568701).

### To change the port and run from multiple directories on different ports:

Now if you need to run the directory on a different port, change the port number from 80 to 8080 by editing the virtualhost file as:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin user@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/work
</VirtualHost>
```

and editing `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and adding `Listen 8080` just below the line `Listen 80`

Now we can enable the default virtualhost configuration file that runs on port 80 since example.com directory uses port 8080, as `sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf`.

Now restart or reload the server with command `sudo service apache2 restart`. Now both the directories can be accessed from `localhost` and `localhost:8080`.

Comment: To run Apache in a user directory you need to add the user to the Apache group and the Apache to the user group. I suggest adding the following 3 commands to the answer: Open the terminal with your user and run: sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER; sudo adduser $USER www-data; sudo adduser www-data $USER;

Answer (score 4):

If you couldn't find `http.conf` and followed [Nick's way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server/12334511#12334511).

Restart Apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 4):

I was working with [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) and ***to change the document root folder***, I have edited the **default** file which is there in the
**/etc/apache2/sites-available** folder.

If you want to do the same, just edit as follows:

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/new_root_folder
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/username/new_root_folder>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

After this, if you type "localhost" in the browser, it will load the ***/home/username/new_root_folder*** content.

Comment: What is the name of the file? `000-default.conf`?

Comment: To run Apache in a user directory you need to add the user to the Apache group and the Apache to the user group. I suggest adding the following 3 commands to the answer: Open the terminal with your user and run: sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER; sudo adduser $USER www-data; sudo adduser www-data $USER;

Answer (score 4):

For **Apache 2** on [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 17.3 [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) 64-bit, the following works:

1. In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` open the `000-default.conf` file, and change the *Document Root* to the absolute path of your directory.

   `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
2. In folder `/etc/apache2/` open file `httpd.conf`, and add a `<Directory>` tag referencing your directory and containing the exact same settings as the tag for `var/www`.

   ```
    sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

   On my machine it looked like this:

   ---

   ```
    <Directory /home/my_user_name/php/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
   ```

*Note:* In the first step you probably want to change *Document Root* in the `default-ssl.conf` file as well for SSL purposes. But as far as I can tell, this isn't required to get a general development environment running.

Answer (score 3):

In Apache  version 2.4.18 (Ubuntu).

1. Open the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and
   search for `<Directory /var/www/>` and replace to your directory.
2. Open file */etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*, search for `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` and replace it with your DocumentRoot.

Comment: I have done both thing. It still show 
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: check your folder permission if it is not in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

The following applies to [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) and later releases. Make sure to back up following files before making any changes.

1. Open `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and search for `<Directory /var/www/>` directive and replace path with `/home/<USERNAME>/public_html`. You can use * instead of .
2. Open `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and change the `DocumentRoot` value property from `/var/www/html` to `/home/<USERNAME>/public_html`. Also `<Directory /var/www/html>` to `<Directory /home/<USERNAME>/public_html`.
3. Open `/etc/mods-available/php7.1.conf`. Find and comment the following code

   php_admin_flag engine Off

Do not turn the `php_admin_flag engine OFF` flag *on* as the reason is mentioned in a comment above the Directive code. Also the PHP version can be 5.0, 7.0 or anything you have installed.

Create `public_html` directory in `home/<USERNAME>`.

Restart the Apache service by executing command `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Test by running a sample script on the server.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), please update the *000-default.conf* file in the directory **/etc/apache2/sites-available**.

Here →

ServerAdmin **webmaster@localhost** 
DocumentRoot **/var/www/html/YourFolder**

Comment: What do you mean by "update"? Removing comment characters? Replacing something with something else? Adding "/YourFolder"? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I had made the `/var/www` to be a soft link to the required directory (for example, `/users/username/projects`) and things were fine after that.

However, naturally, the original `/var/www` needs to be deleted - or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has installed [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) in the `/opt` folder, then the `/etc/apache2` folder is not what you are looking for.

Look for `httpd.conf` file in folder `/opt/lampp/etc`.

Change the line in this folder and save it from the terminal.

Comment: Why two `p`s in `lampp`?

Answer (score 0):

In [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 7.0: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) (personal opinion, from all distributions this one is making me happy), follow this:

1. Go to folder */etc/apache2/sites-available* and edit file *000-default.conf*.
2. Search for DocumentRoot, example *DocumentRoot /var/www/html*. You change to your respective directory;
3. Open a terminal and type: `sudo service apache2 restart`

In Linux Mint, you go for file */etc/apache2/apache.conf*. Replace */var/www* with your respective path, and then restart the server (step 3).

That's it.