# how to change document root in xampp in ubuntu? help documentroot not working

Tags: apache, xampp, document-root

i have read in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server) as to how to change the document root in ubuntu xampp which said to change documentroot value & the <directory> tag values to my preferred address..
i tried and its wasnt working. i realised that my drive is named with spaces in between like "my drive" and after a little search i found that i should use "my\ drive" to include the space in between the words.. but now i have another error..

httpd.conf value:
DocumentRoot "/media/my\ drive/xampp/htdocs"

XAMPP: Error 1! Couldn't start Apache!
XAMPP: Starting diagnose...
XAMPP: Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP: Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/

i checked error_log file which says

[Tue Aug 14 00:08:21 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
[Tue Aug 14 00:08:47 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Syntax error on line 179 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
Syntax error on line 179 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
Syntax error on line 179 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
Syntax error on line 179 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory

it is a valid directory in which i have my windows 8 os installed..

Answer (score 0):

It should work without the \, because there are already quotes around the path. In the directory tag you should be able to put quotes around your path too, if not, try the \ there.

Comment: i have tried with and without \ in both DocumentRoot and directory tags with no luck... what else can be done??

Comment: Trailing slashes? Reading permissions for the user the apache runs on? Just throwing in some ideas.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Maybe you have to add trailing slashes to specified directories for it to work, I've had to work with software which seems to be sensitive about that.
About my second point: If the user under which apache is running (you can check this in the config) does not have reading access to your directory, it may not be recognized as a directory, try to "chmod -R 755" the whole dir (you should not do that in productive environments, just for testing purposes).