# Change public_html directory .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

My folder for public_html is /domain.com/public_html/ but i want the htaccess to redirect them to the folder /domain/public_html/www/ but still have domain.com as domain and not domain.com/www .

EDIT:
I want the subfolder www in the public_html do be the default root and not public_html itself

Any solution on this?

Here is my current htacess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I haven't try anything yet because I haven't found any solution on this

Comment: The question is unprecise and unclear in its current form. Please revise it and try to state more clearly what you want to happen. And don't mix expressions like domain names, paths and urls.

Comment: Added more information and hope it's give a better question to answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can only go for .htaccess, this simple one should do it;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [QSA]
```

---

Explanation;

```
RewriteEngine on                      # Turn on mod_rewrite functionality
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/    # Don't rewrite requests that are 
                                      # already to the /www/ directory. 
                                      # If this isn't here, we'll go into
                                      # a neverending loop.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [QSA]      # Rewrite all else to the www subdirectory
                                      # QSA = keep the query string.
```

EDIT: Didn't see your existing htaccess, this (minus the redundant RewriteEngine statement) should probably go at the end instead of the whole IfModule block.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in the htaccess on the `public_html` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

### **OR**

Edit the apache configuration (`httpd.conf`)

```
vi /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

and set the `DocumentRoot` of the domain as

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/www
```

Save the file and restart the httpd service.

### **OR (recomanded)**

Take a look at this question(and it's answer) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891858/1361042

### **EDIT**

Use this HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [NC, QSA]
</IfModule>
```

don't add it to yours but replace your htaccess with this one.

Comment: I tired the mod_rewrite solution you showed, but it just gives med error 500 and i can't acess httpd.conf because im on shared webhost.

Comment: if you can't access the httpd.conf file, than i'm affraid it is unpossible to change the default root directory.

Comment: I have sended a message to my host(binero.se) and ask if it's possible to change it. Because it's a security reason when I going to have some other ppl acces the site throught ftp

Comment: I havn't seen your current htaccess, change it to my edit in my answer