# How to install drupal on ububtu using source code?

Tags: drupal-7

I want to install drupal in my home folder instead of its default directory in ubuntu 12.04 using source and want configure it with mysql. But I am not getting useful link for it. I am stuck on this.

Comment: I have not much idea why you want this to be done. Try using softlink or hardlink on ubuntu

Comment: try this link.

url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server

Comment: Official community documentation : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal