# can't execute php files after changing default directory

Tags: php, lamp

I'm new to LAMP and running into some troubles trying to install it on Ubuntu 14.04. I changed the DocumentRoot in 000-default.conf to a new folder instead of var/www and now it can't execute .php files.

Below is my etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "full path to folder"

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here is the error I get from /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Fri Oct 17 16:43:19.787413 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2433] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Oct 17 16:54:55.754101 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2433] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Oct 17 16:54:56.851627 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2943] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: @Nikolas: I just did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd say double-check that DocumentRoot.  An ellipses in the directory looks unusual to me.

Comment: `/.../WebFolder/"` three dots? and `WebFolder` is located at the root of the filesystem? `Here is the error` those are not errors.

Comment: @Cheery: I just editted the question.

Comment: Already answered ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server