# Changing root of apache2 is not working

Tags: apache, server, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to change the root directory of my apache2 server on my Ubuntu by following the instructions provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server) But its showing a 403 error. Can anyone guide me through.

[image: 403 error]

Comment: Is there an index in the directory ? If no, try to add a file named index.php.

Comment: I have added the index file but nothing changed