# I have configured a vagrant file, and I need a dev.domain.com pointing to 55.55.55.5/public

Tags: vagrant, hosts, vagrantfile

I have configured a vagrant file, and I need a dev.domain.com pointing to 55.55.55.5/public

My website works with the /public folder, but in the dev.domain.com I need to enter to public/ to see the page, so all styles, javascripts and files that points to "/", are broken due to the /public in the url.

Anyone can help me?

vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "avenuefactory/lamp"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html", create: true, group: "www-data", owner: "www-data"
end
```

hosts file :

```
55.55.55.5 dev.domain.com
```

What I need is "something" making dev.domain.com pointing to 55.55.55.5/public.

Comment: You should configure the webserver inside your vagrant machine to use /var/www/html/public as the document root.

Comment: I can't, because the project is using laravel. So the files in /public use some files in the root.

Comment: Not laravel, but the webserver of your virtual machine: Apache, Ngix, or whatever else your using in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, and I want to share the answer. I use an answer from other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23175981/3685739

I made all this changes through the vagrant ssh, in the webserver.

> Please note, that this only applies for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and newer
>   releases.
>
> In my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the document root was set to /var/www/html. It
>   was configured in the following file:
>
> ```
> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
> ```
>
> So just do a
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
> ```
>
> and change the following line to what you want:
>
> ```
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html
> ```
>
> Also do a
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
> ```
>
> and find this
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/html/>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride None
> Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> and change /var/www/html to your preferred directory
>
> and save it.
>
> After you saved your changes, just restart the apache2 webserver and
>   you'll be done :)
>
> ```
> sudo service apache2 restart
> ```