# Laravel project Installation on xampp

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel, I have installed the laravel on my local server(Xampp) with composer. I have a small project that is build in the laravel now I am getting trouble to run that project on the xampp. 
Thanx in advance

Comment: Could you be specific about the problem?

Comment: For simple php we just copy and paste the project folder to htdocs and than we set the database configuration file, and it works.
But in laravel I dont know how to run it on http://localhost/larave/

Answer (score 0):

Just point your folder in apache.conf to your laravel public folder and you will be able to run your project in windows.
Follow this guide to do so:

[How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

Please read the docs about the installation for any other problems you may have.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation

Comment: Pointing the document root will not affect the other projects??

Comment: Yes but you can create a new site for example localhost2 will point to the project. If  you only working on laravel then you shouldn't wurry about it you can always change it latter if you need.