# Change base directory

Tags: configuration, webserver

I want to change the home directory of my website to one of the child directories within the site so for example

```
http://name_of_site/first_directory/second_directory/index.php
```

would be rewritten to

```
http://name_of_site/index.php
```

Comment: What is the code using it ? it depends how you use it... What is your framework etc... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to change your `DocumentRoot` (Apache) or `root` (Nginx) respectively

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/first_directory/second_directory;
root /path/to/first_directory/second_directory;
```

Also, there are a lot alike question out there

- https://serverfault.com/questions/423624/how-to-change-the-nginx-default-folder
- [How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)