# How to put a folder as DocumentRoot on Apache in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am trying to change the `DocumentRoot` on `Apache` in `Ubuntu`. I want that the main folder will be a directory with the path `/var/something` instead of `/var/www`.

I tried it going to the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and modifying the property `DocumentRoot` from the file `000-default.conf` from `DocumentRoot /var/www` to `DocumentRoot /var/something` but nothing changed. I still see the file that I have as default for the directory `/var/www`.

I also tried doing the same with the `000-default.conf` file on the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and also modifying both at the same time but the result it is the same.

Am I modifying the wrong file or the wrong property?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you put a symlink in `/var/www` that points to `/var/something` you can put  your files in `/var/something` and it will serve them as long as `FollowSymlinks` is set in `httpd.conf`.  Not sure if this is what you're looking for though

Comment: @JordanCamp I need to change my default directory. That when I put `localhost:80` the content of the directory `/var/extras` will be displayed.

Comment: I thing your question might be the same as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my question on the file `apache2.conf` in `/etc/apache2` directory.

I just had to add this line (it does not appear on the file):

```
DocumentRoot /var/something
```

After that I had to restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and now when I try to access to `localhost:80` it shows me the file that it is as default on that folder.