# Laravel unable to load view

Tags: php, laravel-5

Just started learning laravel I tried to create a route for my view but when I load on the web browser it says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. Can any one help me out in codeigniter it was so simple just create a controller and view and we can see on the web broswer I found laravel to be difficult then codigniter is that true?? can anyone define me how is the mvc structure for laravel5 as i found tutorials but they are of old laravel and files and structure are almost change so I got confused any suggestions please

routes.php

```
Route::get('main', 'Main@index');
```

Main.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class main extends Contoller {
    public function _construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index() {
        return "Hello World from controller";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are running laravel project locally, it can run through its own server. you dont need apache server form wamp or xampp,,but you will need their mysql database. So start only that if you require database.

Now go to command prompt, navigate to the directory where your project is stored eg cd c:/wamp/www/yourprojet and then type following command

```
php artisan serve
```

it will start on port 8000 by default. and you can now access  your project at 'http://localhost:8000/'

and you can access your view at 'http://localhost:8000/main'

Also you can find laravel tutorials and other at [laracast](https://laracasts.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the class name to Main (now is main, in lowecase)

I learnt Laravel by their awesome tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick

Comment: I changed Main to main and I am trying to acces like this http://localhost:90/laravel/public/ still not working

Comment: Your web server has to be pointing at the public folder of the laravel installation. Then, you can go to localhost:90/main

Comment: where can i found and configure these

Comment: If you are using Apache without VHosts you can change the web root in httpd.conf, if you are using VHosts point the right one to the folder.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server

Comment: mine is then pointed though right this is my documnet root line DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

Comment: Then change it to your laravel public folder path

Comment: DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public" not working either :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115960/discussion-between-nil-llisterri-and-mark-alan).

Answer (score 0):

make a view in resources->views, something like `my-view.blade.php`

Then `return view('my-view');`

That my-view.blade.php can have whatever HTML you want in it

Answer (score 0):

Go to your resources/views folder create file with `filename.blade.php`.

Now in your `routes.php`:

```php
Route::get('main', 'Main@index');
```

And in your controller add this function:

```php
public function index() {
    return view('filename');
}
```