# How can I change www.mysymfonypage.com/public to www.mysymfonypage.com?

Tags: symfony, url, redirect

When I locally open the url `localhost:8000` then I see my main homepage.

I installed the apache pack (composer require symfony/apache-pack) and uploaded everything via ftp on my server.

This is the `.htaccess` file in my public folder:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I open `www.mysymfonypage.com` and it redirects to the public folder, which is fine. But my URL is now `www.mysymfonypage.com/public`

How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you should reconfigure your webserver to use `/public` as webroot - [How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

Alternatively you could add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

after `RewriteEngine On` - BUT this will 301 redirect all your requests so that would likely cause issues / undesired behaviour somewhere along the line.

Comment: Thank you for the advice to reconfigure the webserver. I try to do it, but cannot find a file in the Symfony configuration called `httpd.conf`

Comment: That's because that file is for the Apache webserver used to host your project - it has nothing to do with Symfony. If you aren't sure what I am talking about this may be something to contact your server admin over as you will likely not have permissions to edit the file anyway.

Comment: So if I am understanding right, I have to login to my shared host service and make the change there? So far as I understand this documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html they are providing the code (like `DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public` I have to write into some document. My big question is, where is this document?

Comment: My host recommend to use rewrite engine in htaccess. But you said it will cause problems

Comment: If you're on shared hosting you will likely not have access to that document. There may be a way to do it through the provided management GUI for your webserver but it really depends on the provider / setup. At this stage I think you will need to contact support or hit the documentation provided by your host...

Comment: A question to your rewrite recommendation: Do I have to change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]` into `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]`?