# How to access about us html file from the default index html file in localhost?

Tags: html, localhost

**Only HTML Files (in same folder):**

I have 2 files `index.html` and `aboutus.html`. I am running mysite without any file it opens index.html (by default which I know) but when I click on "About Us" (aboutus.html) it does not open aboutus.html. Nothing happening!

I have written the following code in `index.html`

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a>
</div>
```

I am using localhost to test the files. I am newbie and I have no idea where I am wrong.

Comment: Did the url changed?

Comment: Press F12 and look in the network console

Comment: I am using same directory as per `Only HTML Files (in same folder):`

Comment: Can you share the full HTML of index.html? I think you maybe have a base tag inside head.

Comment: Did you check your root directory from your server? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

Comment: A common mistake is to name the file extension ".htm" and use ".html" or viceversa.

Comment: Another mistake is to have the case wrong on a Microsoft server. - like AboutUs.html which is not the same as aboutus.html

Comment: Thanks guys!!  I got my answer from this conversation....

Answer (score 1):

Your `./index.html` and `./aboutus.html` files should be in the SAME directory.

Also make sure you do not have any `<base>` tags inside the `<head></head>` tags of your document as this will force the browser to look for the aboutus file in a different directory.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your HTML tags so other than the above, it should work.

Please check to see if the URL changed - perhaps the content of `index.html` and `aboutus.html` is the same, and as such you didn't notice a difference?

Alternatively you should use `F12` to launch the developer console to see if any errors are generated.