# Is there any solution for not adding sub directory public in every links in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my problem for a long year. 
every time I deployed the project always I add public sub directory to the css / images / JavaScript to the links. i will demonstrate here on the below the comparison.

**Question:** Is there way not to put the sub directory of public.?

**Localhost VS Deployed project on apache.**

Localhost:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<link href="{{ asset('datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.Auth::user()->profile_image)}}" class="img-profile rounded-circle" style="width:40px !important; height:40px !important;">
```

Production:

```
<script src="{{asset('/public/js/jquery.min.js')}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<link href="{{ asset('/public/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="{{asset('/public/storage/'.Auth::user()->profile_image)}}" class="img-profile rounded-circle" style="width:40px !important; height:40px !important;">
```

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like the document root on your apache server is not properly set to the 'public' directory. Please see this answer on how to set your Apache root directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891858/11182541. There might be easier ways to set the root directory if you are using a managed service to host your application

Comment: @EdenDowling-Mitchell i already point the root directory to the project folder.

Comment: And do you point it to the 'public' folder within your project folder? It should be pointing to `/path/to/project/folder/public`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

Comment: @EdenDowling-Mitchell why do you mean for that? can you show to me the sample foldering?

Answer (score 0):

No need /public.

```
<link href="{{asset('css/jquery-ui.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```