# OXID starting on localhost/source, I want to start it at localhost

Tags: xampp, localhost, oxid

My OXID store starts on localhost with http://localhost/source, but I just want it to start with http://localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the DocumentRoot setting in your httpd.conf file. You also have to change the corresponding Directory Setting in the same file. Both should point to the "source" directory. [How do I change the root directory of an Apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

In your Oxid installation you then have to change the "sShopURL" setting in config.inc.php to http://localhost/, and additionally you have to change "RewriteBase /source" to "RewriteBase /" in your .htaccess file (both of these files are in the "source" directory of your shop).

Remember that you have to remove the write protection from the config.inc.php file in order to edit it. One more Tip: if you are using xampp you can edit the httpd.conf file and restart apache in the xampp control panel.