# How do I set up my public_html dir in EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

For most of my projects on my school server, we used a public_html dir to put our html and php files into.

I am trying to set up a EC2 server (with Ubuntu) to host my personal projects and I want to have a public_html folder so I can maintain the way I have my files organized.
I have set the permissions of the public_html dir to 705 and have a test file named index.html.
While I can host html files out of var/www/html, I don't want to do that.

Some of my readings suggest changing the DocumentRoot in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file but I don't know what I need to change or at how many places.

Please help me solve this or recommend resources as I am new to Linux.

Comment: I think [these responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server) will help you on achieving it.

Comment: The fact that the Apache server is running on an Amazon EC2 instance is not relevant. (It's like saying that it is running on a Dell or an HP computer.) The linked question should provide the information you seek.